# How can we get the soil type, temperature and rain from API 2.0?

Tags: geojson

We were using the v1 of the SoilGrids REST API and previously we were able to get the soil type, rain and temperature. We used the following values:

For the API v1, the query required only the latitude and longitude of the location we wanted to know about.

```
GET https://rest.soilgrids.org/query?\
     lat=xxxxx&lon=yyyyy\
     &attributes=TAXOUSDA,TMDMOD,PREMRG\
```

And then I used the response to pull the values of soil type, temperature, and precipitation.

```
$soil_properties[ 'soil_type' ] = $result->properties->TAXGOUSDAMajor;
$soil_properties[ 'temp' ] = $result->properties->TMDMOD_2011->M
$soil_properties[ 'rain' ] = $result->properties->PREMRG->M
```

Now the API v1 is returning a 404. The new version [(API 2.0)](https://rest.soilgrids.org/soilgrids/v2.0/docs) doesn't appear to provide these values.

Where can I get them?

Comment: What API are you referring to?

Comment: its possible that the API request structure has changed, or property names have changed, if they have upgraded it to a newer version. Which API are you talking about here?

Comment: I was using that from the REST v1 API. .. now I want to do the same but with the 2.0 API from https://rest.soilgrids.org/soilgrids/v2.0/docs or maybe with another API that allows me pull the values.

Comment: Hi @AndrésSmerkin ... I took a look at the docs and see what you mean. I don't know, but it is possible that they removed such variables so that they can focus on a smaller set of data products. For example it is probably a better idea to get weather data from another site such as DayMet (there are many others - do you want annual means? a daily time series). And you can classify the soil into the USDA taxonomy classes based on values of sand / silt / clay. And if you are doing analyses it might be better to use sand/silt/clay as covariates rather than the USDA classifications.

Comment: This R package gets a few other globa datasets https://stineb.github.io/ingestr/. And the soil_class function of the rcropmod https://github.com/ldemaz/rcropmod package will return categories from sand/silt/clay